# Getting segfault on GLuint program = glCreateProgram(); in android native app

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm trying to get an android native activity (fully ndk) to run openGL code.. I've looked around a lot, and spent quite a bit of time on IRC.  All roads lead me to naught.

In my app_gradle I've got the following lines

```
 ldFlags.add("-lGLESv2")
 ldFlags.add("-lGLESv1_CM")
 ldLibs.addAll(["log", "android", "EGL", "GLESv1_CM", "GLESv2"])
```

I believe that should link the correct libs (Might be overkill)

In my code (main.c) I've got this

```
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>

GLuint loadGLProgram() {
  LOGI("GETTING HERE 1");

  GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
  LOGI("GETTING HERE 2");
....
  return program;
}
```

When I run this code.

```
...native-activity: GETTING HERE 1
...A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 2965 (native_activity)
```

I'm wondering if anyone has seen this, or if anyone has ever found/created a simple openGL example that is truly native.

---

Here's a more detailed log. Still digging.

```
03-29 22:13:55.030 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-29 22:13:55.030 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:6.0/MASTER/2524533:userdebug/test-keys'
03-29 22:13:55.030 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
03-29 22:13:55.030 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
03-29 22:13:55.030 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG: pid: 2109, tid: 2124, name: com.Little.Aisy  >>> com.Little.Aisy <<<
03-29 22:13:55.030 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
03-29 22:13:55.040 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     eax f69d9ec0  ebx eb7b8d58  ecx e7ecd12c  edx e7ecd12c
03-29 22:13:55.040 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     esi e4b63930  edi e4b63970
03-29 22:13:55.040 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 00000007  xss 0000002b
03-29 22:13:55.040 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     eip 00000000  ebp e4b63748  esp e4b636ec  flags 00210292
03-29 22:13:55.040 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
03-29 22:13:55.050 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000  <unknown>
03-29 22:13:55.050 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00002a66  /data/app/com.Little.Aisy-2/lib/x86/libnative-activity.so
03-29 22:13:55.050 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00003076  /data/app/com.Little.Aisy-2/lib/x86/libnative-activity.so
03-29 22:13:55.050 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00003ab3  /data/app/com.Little.Aisy-2/lib/x86/libnative-activity.so
03-29 22:13:55.050 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00003208  /data/app/com.Little.Aisy-2/lib/x86/libnative-activity.so (android_main+236)
03-29 22:13:55.050 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00003be5  /data/app/com.Little.Aisy-2/lib/x86/libnative-activity.so
03-29 22:13:55.050 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00081933  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+56)
03-29 22:13:55.050 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000227f2  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+25)
03-29 22:13:55.050 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000170b6  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
03-29 22:13:55.180 1013-1013/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_08
03-29 22:13:55.180 1013-1013/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
```

Comment: How do you setup your OpenGL context? While on Android/GLES2 glCreateProgram should be available readily, you still need a working context to be able to use it.

Comment: context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, NULL);
Is that what you mean?

Comment: This does let me paint the screen colors.. and is in one of the samples..

Comment: There should be a stack trace following an error like that. Can you make sure your logcat filter is set to 'No Filters' (it typically defaults to 'Show only selected application') and check for a stack trace following the SIGSEGV error?

Comment: According to the stack trace, the program counter is at 0x0, i.e. you've jumped through a null pointer. Do any other `gl` functions work at that point, or do they all crash the same way? (Wondering if there's a table of vectors that isn't initialized.)

Comment: the glCreateShader also falls down the same way (if it's run first).. I fully expect it's an init thing, but I'll be buggered if I know what it is.

Comment: Can you think of any stand alone gl methods that could test the theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, you are indicating that you are creating your context with the following call:

```
context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, NULL);
```

If you use [eglCreateContext](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreateContext.xhtml) with a NULL `attrib_list` parameter, a GLES 1.0 context will be created. GLES 1.0 does not support shaders, thus, using `glCreateProgram` will result in undefined behavior (crash in this case). To create your context with GLES 2.0 support, use the following:

```
EGLint contextAttribs[] =
{
    EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, // Specifies OpenGL ES 2.0.
    EGL_NONE
};
context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, contextAttribs);
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know of a sample that show how to use this would you?

Comment: There are pretty limited examples of native activities out there, because most people use the Java layer. All the EGL/GLES calls made in native have identical ones called in Java, so any sample you can find that's written in Java (of which, there are *many*) can be fairly easily be converted to the NDK. This includes EGL and the creation of an GLES2 context - eg. if you look at hello-gl2 in the NDK samples, it uses the same attributes to create the context.

Comment: Yeah.. but I'm trying to stay out of Java, so I can move to IOS with greater ease.  Now that I know what I'm missing, I'll take a closer look at that and the triangle sample too.